# MySQL - Storing Array and doing a Search based on value

Tags: mysql, arrays, sqldatatypes

I have an Activity Feed Module where i am storing Activity that's happening in a Company that has multiple members. The Activities are usually specific to USERs based on their Role. So i want to store the Users whom the activity should be shown to inside the table column so that while fetching the activities i do not have to query the users associated with that activity which would slow down the Data retrieval process.

since MySQL does not have array data type which is the best way to do it?

Right now i have

```
activities(id, category, action, date)
activity_users(id, activity_id, user_id)
```

Is This easier to query the activities which are based on the particular type of users that to add a column `users` and story an array `[1,3,5,8]` and try to query that from the `activities` table

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use serialize() / unserialize()  but you cant fire query on that fields the if need anything specific from that serialized data ( you ll have to fetch all , unserialize and then can perform search )  OR  you can save data comma separated ( you can perform any query on that )  OR you can get seprate field for each data

Comment: can i do a query on the comma separated store? is like a search query? or does it makes sense to have another table itself?

Comment: You can use  find_in_set  mysql function for comma separated fields

Answer (score 0):

If your code in `<?php` you can use `json_encode()`/`json_decode()`, `serialize()`/`unserialize()` and write string as normal. But it will be hard to build right condition for select this kind of data. If u need to find somthing use `%LIKE%` - not always helps. I suggest you to create separate fields for each kind of data.